# How do I redirect my customer to another site once they have clicked the UPI pay button

Tags: javascript, html, payment, gateway, upi

So I have basically created a UPI pay button. I want the link to automatically redirect once it evokes the UPI payment apps. For eg once customer clicks on pay button, UPI app show and in background he gets redirected.

I was expecting that customer can got to payment checking page once they click the UPI pay button

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.